# How to print a value as a hex

Tags: python

I'm able to read a hexadecimal value from a file and multiply it, but how could I print it out as a hex too. Following prints value as an integer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

f = open('file.dat', 'r')
f.seek(44)
value  = int(f.read(1), 16)*2
print value
f.close()
```

output: 12

Comment: This question is not a duplicate because it's about formatting, the other questions are about conversion.

Answer (score 9):

```
print hex(value)
```

Just cast it to a hex value as you print it

Comment: *solution for Python 3+* `print ('0x{:x}'.format(255))  # prints 0xff`